# Need to refactor public class

Tags: c#

I have the following code and I'm not sure how to best refactor it.  What is happening is the code is only processing the 2nd "public MyShipService" but I need to call both (or refactor to make both work).  Any ideas?

```
public class MyShipService : AnotherService, IShipService

public MyShipService(IStateService stateservice)
{
        _shipToService = new CallShipService();
        _stateService = stateService;
}
public MyShipService(ICountryService countryservice)
{
           _shipToService = new CallShipService();
        _countryService = countryService;
}
shippingAddresses.Each(sa => sa.State =_stateService.GetStateByAbbrev(sa.State.TwoLetterAbbr));
shippingAddresses.Each(sa => sa.Country = _countryService.GetCountryByAbbrev(sa.Country.TwoLetterAbbr));
return shippingAddresses;
```

Comment: So why not just pull the common code from `do stuff` and `do same stuff as above` into a private method which both of the `MyShipService` methods can call?

Comment: Makes sense on moving to a private method but the issue is that MyShipService must be called twice so that it can point to diffrent services. What the code is doing is processing MyShipService and looking at the state repository to return back state information for the shipment, then I need it to also look at the ICountryService to lookup the country information for that order.      The class is only calling the 2nd Public MyShipService and ignoring the 1st one.

Comment: Is your second constructor doing the SAME thing as the first constructor, or is it running that code and then running its own additional code?

Comment: Your class declaration shows overloaded constructors, and there is no way to invoke both constructors (other than chaining them). Why can't you have a constructor that takes both a `IStateService` parameter and a `ICountryService` parameter

Comment: I included more of the code which may help.  I apologize but I am new to c# so any examples you can provide may help.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys..total brain fart.

Final code that worked is..
    public MyShipService(IStateService stateservice, ICountryservice countryservice)
    {
            _shipToService = new CallShipService();
            _stateService = stateService;
            _countryService = countryService;
    }